# How to dynamically allocate memory to a array of array in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following C `struct`:

```
typedef struct {

    char *name;
    int nfollowers;
    char *followers[];
} User;
```

There's a point in my code where I have to allocate memory for the last variable of the `struct` (`followers`) and I'm having issues on it.

I have tried this:

```
users[nusers].followers = (char **) realloc(users[nusers].followers, sizeof(char));
```

or this

```
users[nusers].followers = (char **) realloc(users[nusers].followers, sizeof(char *));
```

but the output I get after compiling is the following:

> error: invalid use of flexible array member

How can I properly do this?

**EDIT**

Example of how my C file is structured:

```
 User *users;
 int i=0, n, nusers=0;
 char aux, *str;
 
 fd_in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
 
 if (fd_in >= 0) {

    users = (User *) malloc(sizeof(User));

    while (aux!='&') {

        users[nusers].followers = (char **) realloc(users[nusers].followers, sizeof(char)); //Issue

          while (aux != '#') {
              ...
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: This should probably be just `char** followers`. Where's the original `malloc` or `calloc`?

Comment: `users[nusers].followers` looks invalid, too, like if `nusers` is the number of users then that's 1 off the end of the array.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Including creation of `users`.

Comment: Was it your intention to make `followers` a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)? Or was it supposed to be a normal array member?

Comment: It's supposed to be a flexible array, yes. Also I have not done a malloc or calloc before because I read that a realloc acts as a malloc if there isn't previous memory allocated for that variable...

Comment: `sizeof(User)` does not include any space for the flexible array member. Therefore, you are allocating memory only for all other struct members, but not for `followers`. Due to this, even accessing `followers[0]` will be an out of bounds memory access. If you want to allocate space for your flexible array member, you must allocate more memory than `sizeof(User)`.

Comment: `realloc` acts like `mailloc` if the pointer is `NULL`. When working with a FAM, you allocate for the struct and FAM at the same time. Currently your FAM is an array of pointers to `char`. So you need to know how many pointers you want when you allocate for your struct. For example, if you want 10 pointers, you would allocate `User *users = calloc (1, sizeof *users + 10 * sizeof *users->followers);` There can only be one FAM, so you cannot have an array of `User`, and the `User` stuct cannot be nested within another struct.

Comment: [FAM Example](https://paste.opensuse.org/3004357) trivially using string-literals as storage for followers. Additionally, In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Re “It's supposed to be a flexible array”: There is nothing in C called a *flexible array*. You were asked whether `followers` should be a *flexible array member*. An explanation of that is given in the link in the question you were asked. If that is not what you intended, or you do not understand it, answer “no,” not “yes.”

Comment: Yes. I don't know how many users will the program need to read. That's why I used a realloc, to increase the memory needed for the variable `users` when needed. Sorry if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Your code sample does not have proper use of `users`, let alone `users[something].followers`. If that was a sample created just for the question, fix it or use actual code from your work so far. Get working code without use of `followers` first, then ask about making `followers` work.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for your answer, it helped a lot to understand how this type of functions can work in this cases. Also, if I don't know the amount of pointers till the program executes, can't I use a realloc?

Comment: Sure, you can use `realloc` on the struct with the FAM to increase the number of elements of the FAM, just like you would realloc anything else. The struct with FAM provides a single-allocation/single-free of all data which makes is convenient to use with `realloc`. So in my example in the comment above, if you wanted to double the FAM elements, you would `realloc` and replace `10` with `20` -- but always `realloc()` using a temporary pointer and validate the realloc succeeds before assigning the temp pointer to your original.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's the issue I asked about, how to allocate memory for `users[something].followers`. That line of code using that variable is what I tried but didn't work.

Comment: @user157629: Yes, you can use `realloc` to increase the size of a memory allocation. However, increasing the size of the array using `realloc` every time you want to add an element is inefficient. Therefore, you should not do this if you frequently have to add elements. In that case, you may want to consider using a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) instead.

Comment: @user157629: The code you have shown does not work for `users`. Fix that first. Forget about `follwers` until that is done.

Comment: [Same Example with realloc()](https://paste.opensuse.org/99013246) will hopefully explain the user of a temporary pointer to realloc, so when (not if) `realloc()` fails, you don't overwrite your original pointer with `NULL` losing your data and creating a memory-leak due to loss of the original pointer address that was overwritten with `NULL`. Only after validating that `realloc()` succeeds do you assign the reallocated block of memory to your original pointer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by tadman, instead of `char *followers[];` use `char **followers;` to declare the field.

Also watch out that malloc does not initialize memory (though on linux the memory might be initialized to 0 if it has not been reused) so your use of realloc may result in corrupting the heap. Instead, just use malloc again (or use calloc to allocate the struct).

Comment: I'm not sure if calling `realloc` with a [wild pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) is likely to corrupt the heap. My guess is that it is much more likely to cause a crash (segmentation fault or access violation).

Comment: Same thing, really: just a matter of when that crash happens. Sometimes it's in the call to realloc, other times it might be in a call to free or malloc. This is why debugging such things can be very difficult.